# 646/tcp open unknown

Tags: port, nmap

when I make

```
nmap localhost
```

I get

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
25/tcp  open  smtp
111/tcp open  rpcbind
631/tcp open  ipp
646/tcp open  unknown
```

what is the port 646 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to see whats running on that port with

```
netstat -tunlp | grep 646
```

From the comments

```
tcp     0     0     0.0.0.0:646     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN     2584/rpc.statd
```

This indicates that [rpc.statd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rpc.statd) (PID 2584) is listening on port 646. The rpc.statd process is part of the implementation of NFS.

Comment: I get this 
     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:646                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2584/rpc.statd

Comment: there goes your answer

Comment: @JuanPablo: see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since the question has already been answered, I'll provide an answer with a little more background.

Nmap shows open ports by attempting to connect to them. If it receives a positive response, it reports the port as open, and gives a little more information (the `SERVICE` column) based on a table lookup in the `nmap-services` file. For ports that don't have an entry in that file, it reports `unknown`.

The operating system of the scanned machine knows all about what ports are open, since it has to handle the lower layers of network communication in order to hand the data off to the application (or program) that is listening for it. On Windows, Linux, and most *nix systems, users can get the information about open ports directly from the OS by using the `netstat` command. Further, with the `-p` option (`-b` on Windows), privileged users (e.g. root) can see the name and process ID (PID) that is using each port.

Nmap is not limited to looking up port information in `nmap-services`. When a user requests service version detection (`-sV`), Nmap sends data to the ports it discovers as open, then compares the responses to an extensive list of service fingerprints, generating more detailed information, like so:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE            VERSION
646/tcp open  rstatd (rstatd V1) 1 (rpc #100001)
```